# Trapping time and site population

Tags: quantum-mechanics, biophysics, open-quantum-systems

In thr article [environment assisted quantum transport](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0929), the trapping time probability for the FMO complex, a measure of the energy transfer efficiency, is defined $2\kappa_3\int^\infty_0 dt\langle 3|\rho(t)|3\rangle$. Now, this is the integral of the site 3 exciton population as well. However, take a look at this plot of the site populations (site 3 is the dark blue curve, from [Theoretical examination of quantum coherence in a photosynthetic system at physiological temperature](http://www.pnas.org/content/106/41/17255.full)):

[image: site population]

The site population of site 3 is increasing. However, the energy transfer efficiency is known to be around 95% at this temperature, implying the integral of the site population converges. How can this be the case?

Comment: Integral of *what* from zero to infinity? What are the integers in the plot legends?

Comment: @DanielSank i have edited it, is it better?

Comment: Yes, it's more clear. I don't understand the question though. Surely the curve doesn't increase arbitrarily into the future for infinite time.

Comment: @DanielSank no it doesnt, but after a while, the population of site 3 becomes constant...

Comment: Are you confused because you need to normalize the integral by $1/\text{total time}$ or something?

Comment: @DanielSank what do you mean?

Comment: Are the dimensions of $\kappa_3$ 1/time? If so then forget my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

More research confirms @DanielSank's comment. This plot shows the dynamics for a longer period of time (from [Efficient estimation of energy transfer efficiency in light-harvesting complexes](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3823.pdf)):

[image]

As you can see, due to loss and trapping, the exciton population of site 3 decreases after some time, just as @MarkMitchison and @DanielSank mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you include both the ground state $|0\rangle$ where the recombination happens and a state for reaction center (RC) $|rc\rangle$ in your Hamiltonian, you will observe that at a long-time, most of the population transfers to RC and a fraction to state $|0\rangle$ (because of recombination).

You can find the efficiency and trapping time using Eqs.11 and 12 of this reference, respectively. https://doi.org/10.1021/ct200126d

If you wanna explicitly include states $0\rangle$ and $|rc\rangle$, you need to pade your Hamiltonian with zeros to have that extra dimensions.

OR
You can just directly subtract the loss term (transfer to RC) from the population of site-3 $-\Gamma_{loss}\{|rc\rangle\langle rc|, .\}$ and recombination term from each site - $-\Gamma_{recomb} \{|0\rangle \langle 0|, .\}$. In this case, the efficiency can be withdrawn from site-3.